# What is the easiest way to save a variable using shared preferences in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

What is the easiest way to save and load this variable using shared preferences (kotlin)?

```
var score = 12.5
```

And yes the score variable is a double not int.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question because it's not detailed and they are using java not kotlin, i want to get an answer on how you can do that using kotlin.

Comment: Use float, also checkout this library: https://github.com/chibatching/Kotpref

Comment: No i didn't learn Java i learnt python

Answer (score -1):

To put inside:

```
with(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()){
 putDouble("SCORE",score)
 apply()
}
```

To retrieve:

```
val score = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getDouble("SCORE",0.0)
```